# How to exclude jersey 1.x dependencies when running tests with gradle

Tags: gradle, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client, netflix-eureka

We have a web service project that relies on Netflix's Eureka and it has a dependency on Jersey client 1.x.

Our project is using gradle and in the project we have our src, unit, integration, and functional tests. For our functional tests we have a jar that we import in the testCompile gradle section that wraps a Jersey client to send requests to the web service.

Now my question is how can I get the netflix Jersey client dependency to be ignored in the testCompile so I can use the new Jersey 2.x client for the functional tests?

Build Scripts below:

Main service build script excerpt:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:1.1.97'
  compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:1.18'

  testCompile 'some.domain:service-test-client:1.0.1'    
}
```

service test client relevant parts:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.19'
  compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jeresey-apache-connector:2.19'
}
```

Relevant parts of the Eureka Client gradle script from github:

```
ext {
    githubProjectName = 'eureka'
    awsVersion='1.9.3'
    servletVersion='2.5'
    jerseyVersion='1.11'
    governatorVersion='1.3.3'
    archaiusVersion='0.6.5'
    blitzVersion='1.34'
    mockitoVersion='1.9.5'
    junit_version='4.10'
    mockserverVersion='3.9.2'
    jetty_version='7.2.0.v20101020'
}

dependencies {
  compile "com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:$jerseyVersion"
  compile "com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:$jerseyVersion"
  compile 'com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:1.11'
  compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1'

}
```

With the above setup I get method not found errors because when the tests are running some of the jersey 1.x classes are taking precedence over the classes brought in with the test-client jar.

Comment: Please add relevant part of gradle script.

Comment: See [eureka jersey2 client](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/tree/master/eureka-client-jersey2). Though you may want to keep an eye on it, as the README says it's still a work in progress

Answer (score 0):

You can use gradle dependency monitoring to find out what libraries are bringing in jersey.

```
./gradlew dependencies
```

You can pipe that into a file, and `less` your way into finding out who's bringing in jersey 1.*.

Then, just exclude it from those specifically, and compile your own:

```
compile("com.example.library:artifactId:x.y.z"){
   exclude group:'org.glassfish.jersey', module:jersey-common
}

compile('org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.4.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem with jersey 1.x vs glassfish 2.x with Eureka (but with Spring Cloud). I'm trying this:

```
compile ("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka:1.0.0.RELEASE")
{
 exclude group:'com.sun.jersey', module: 'jsr311-api'
}
```

But then Eureka doesn't work for me...

I think I will try to switch to Eureka 2.0 with different jersey, but without spring cloud:
https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-2.0-Architecture-Overview
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.eureka check Eureka2 dependencies

maybe you can use them?

Comment: We can't switch to Eureka 2.0 atm. Once its out of beta we will be allowed to switch though.